# Root permission errror when running clion with devcontainer

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, clion, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to setup clion using the devcontainer support according to the guide on clion website.
**The container creation is successful** but somehow get this error over and over when trying to download and start clion in the container

```
2024-01-15 12:51:31,897 [ 390722]   WARN - #c.j.g.s.GoHighLevelHostAccessor - An error occurred while execution command: 'host-status --ide-path=/root/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c041d69a96728_CLion-2023.3.2 --project-path=/workspace/MyProject'
Exit code: 1
Stderr: ''
Stdout: '{"type":"error","errorCode":"CommandError","data":"Command /root/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c041d69a96728_CLion-2023.3.2/bin/remote-dev-server.sh failed.\nStdout: \nStderr: \n\nCaused by: fork/exec /root/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c041d69a96728_CLion-2023.3.2/bin/remote-dev-server.sh: no such file or directory"}'
2024-01-15 12:51:31,898 [ 390723]   WARN - #c.j.g.s.GoHighLevelHostAccessor - The status command provided error result.
Error code: CommandError
Error:
Command /root/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c041d69a96728_CLion-2023.3.2/bin/remote-dev-server.sh failed.
Stdout: 
Stderr: 

Caused by: fork/exec /root/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c041d69a96728_CLion-2023.3.2/bin/remote-dev-server.sh: no such file or directory
2024-01-15 12:51:34,249 [ 393074] SEVERE - #c.i.o.r.u.RdCoroutineHost - Unhandled coroutine throwable
java.lang.NullPointerException: execOnIO(...) must not be null
```

I'm not running clion as root, I have the idea.config.path and idea.system.path configured to a custom path on my home directory

Comment: Hello! Could you please submit a new issue in our YouTrack using [this draft](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?draftId=25-5085044) and share the `devcontainer.json` and other files you use to build a DevContainer? I want to try to reproduce it on my side.